# Generating a block of seq in R

Tags: r

How can I generate similar sequences in R without using loops? For example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19] and so on. This can be interpreted as follows: if indexes are weekdays, I want to choose only not weekend (or weekend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want numbers till 50. One way using vector recycling could be :

```
n <- 1:50
n[rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(5, 2))]

#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  8  9 10 11 12 15 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 26 29
#[22] 30 31 32 33 36 37 38 39 40 43 44 45 46 47 50
```

---

Or another way :

```
n[n %% 7 %in% 1:5]
```